# where is the official documentation for .Alpha_j_

Tags: j

David Lambert's code [here](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/David_Lambert/isoparametric_shape_functions) gets the letters (Alphabet), using the following:

```
26}.Alpha_j_   NB. output is abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Where can I find the offical documentation for "**.Alpha_j_**"?
I have searched [NuVoc](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/NuVoc), and the closest I found is [adot](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/adot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really documentation, but it is defined in the `stdlib.ijs` file on line 1661. Found in `j901/system/main/stdlib.ijs`  Probably the reason that you got the documentation for `a.` (Alphabet) from Nuvoc is because that is how it is constructed as a subset of the characters in the primitve `a.`

```
cocurrent <'j'
Alpha=: a. {~ , (a.i.'Aa') +/ i.26
```

I noticed that you called it `.Alpha_j_`, but actually it is named Alpha and the dot comes from the `}.` (Drop) which is used to drop the first 26 letters which are upper case. The `_j_` suffix indicates it is part of the `j` locale (a namespace).

```
   Alpha_j_
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer + explanation on prefix/postfix (I just thought it was an unusual variable name). It is liberating to know I can search the [Github source code](https://github.com/jsoftware/jsource/search?q=alpha+filename%3Astdlib.ijs) directly to get any definition in the future! In this case, the search term is "`alpha filename:stdlib.ijs`".

Comment: Not all definitions are in `stdlib.ijs` though. Many other `.ijs` files within the system folder have definitions in them that show up in standard J in different locales. If you are working in the JHS or jQt environments then there are even more under `addons/ide/jhs/` or `addons/ide/jqt/`